# Magento 2.3.1 upgrade Errors

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade magento2.2.3 CE to 2.3.1CE on staging server (magemojo)

After upgraded getting the below errors. Please can anyone face these below issues suggest me how to fix?

1.Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error

fallowed this link https://magecomp.com/blog/solved-unable-to-unserialize-value-magento-2-2/

2.Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config

3.PHP 7.1.27 currently using.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade your php version to 7.1.X or above and install all the required below php packages:

- PDO/MySQL
- mbstring
- mcrypt
- mhash
- simplexml
- curl
- gd2, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both
- soap

Comment: hi @saphal jha currently i am using PHP 7.1.27 currently using.

Comment: are you using reddis cache or other?

Comment: please check your app/etc/env.php file, if you are using those cache(reddiss/varnish/mem) then you need to flush them.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nrcln4 please check this once

Comment: you need to flish this vernish cache using ssh.

Comment: Hi @saphal Jha after upgraded, unabele to view attribute set section at product level https://prnt.sc/nrfncq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93923/discussion-between-saphal-jha-and-nagaraju-kasa).

Answer (score 0):

> Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config

I ran into this error when deploying code updates to a Magento 2.3.2 site using Capistrano. I solved the problem by flushing the Redis cache (as Saphal Jha suggested):

```
cat app/etc/env.php
```

Example output from that command:

```
<?php
return [
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => '/var/run/redis-multi-aa45d208.redis/redis.sock',
            'port' => '6379',
            …
        ]
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '/var/run/redis-multi-aa45d208.redis/redis.sock',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => '6379'
                ],
                'id_prefix' => '7ef_'
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '/var/run/redis-multi-aa45d208.redis/redis.sock',
                    'database' => '2',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'compress_data' => '0'
                ],
                'id_prefix' => '7ef_'
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

After identifying the Redis information, I flushed the Redis cache, which solved my issue:

```
redis-cli -s /var/run/redis-multi-aa45d208.redis/redis.sock flushall
```